# Hover background not centered on items in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I tried without success to modify hovering effects on navbar. The idea is to make appear a small rectangle when I hover link (vertically centered). The rectangle should be smaller than the total height of the navbar.

Right now, I get a strange effect on hover link and dropdown doesn't work anymore
[image]

i created a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/edsO0A04t1) of my problem

Comment: I suggest adding an image of your desired result to help people visualize the results you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it's a very good idéa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, You need to add `<span>` tag in `<a>` tag. also, need to some modification in css.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="/"><span>About</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="/"><span>Contact</span></a></li>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span>Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.nav > li > a span
{ 
  height: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px;
}
ul.nav > li > a:hover span
{ 
  background-color: #f0f0f0 !important; 
  border-radius: 6px !important;
}
ul.nav > li > a{padding-right:0px; padding-left:0px;}
```

also, Check it [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jkef33b2Ae)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the height as shown below for your ul.nav

```
ul.nav > li > a:hover
{ 
     background-color: #f0f0f0 !important; 
     border-radius: 6px !important;
     height: 35px;//Change according to your wish
     margin-top:5px;//You can add this too
}
```

Check here [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DbNO4jWOkl#)